# Merge array elements on common field in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have the following two arrays that I would like to reduce / combine. EMAIL should be unique.

Array 1:

```
[
  {
    "EMAIL": "email1@myDomain.com",
    "INUSE": "1"
  },
  {
    "EMAIL": "email4@myDomain.com",
    "INUSE": "1"
  },
  {
    "EMAIL": "email7@myDomain.com",
    "INUSE": "1"
  },
  {
    "EMAIL": "email2@myDomain.com",
    "INUSE": "3"
  }
]
```

Array 2:

```
[
  {
    "EMAIL": "email1@myDomain.com",
    "FREE": "1"
  },
  {
    "EMAIL": "email3@myDomain.com",
    "FREE": "2"
  },
  {
    "EMAIL": "email4@myDomain.com",
    "FREE": "2"
  }
]
```

`jq -s 'add'` combines the array. I did some research on `unique` and `reduce` but I can’t get it to work.

Desired Output:

```
[
  {
    "EMAIL": "email1@myDomain.com",
    "FREE": "1",
    "INUSE": "1"
  },
  {
    "EMAIL": "email4@myDomain.com",
    "INUSE": "1",
    "FREE": "2"
  },
  {
    "EMAIL": "email7@myDomain.com",
    "INUSE": "1"
  },
  {
    "EMAIL": "email2@myDomain.com",
    "INUSE": "3"
  },
  {
    "EMAIL": "email3@myDomain.com",
    "FREE": "2"
  }
]
```

Note that EMAIL values are unique. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `group_by`, not `unique`. After concatenating inputs, group resulting array's elements by `.EMAIL`, and merge members of each group to get the desired outcome.

```
jq -s 'add | group_by(.EMAIL) | map(add)'
```

Comment: That’s great, I was expecting something more complex. Would it also be possible to perform a mathematical operation, like addition, in case both arrays would contain both keys FREE and INUSE?

Comment: @florit There are many ways to perform this operation, and this is just one of them; it is simple, but slow and memory-exhaustive. Yes, that would be possible, but not as easy. You can ask another question for that or edit this one and unaccept my answer.